# How do the C and C++ standards tell you to deal with situations that are not covered by them?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, standards, iso

It is well known that in each of the C and C++ standards there were "blind spots" that did not describe certain cases in well-formed programs. It is obvious that in non-formal descriptions of such complex formal systems it is impossible to notice everything in advance.

Because of this, there is an established procedure for correcting and interpreting a standard until a new revision ("edition") is issued. Let's consider this using the simplest and chronologically first example - the C90 standard ([ISO/IEC 9899:1990](https://www.iso.org/standard/17782.html)), which has now been officially withdrawn.

The following types of documents were issued for it, in order of decreasing importance:

1. **ISO Technical Corrigendum (TC)**

   In fact, these are a kind of "patches" that are applied directly to the existing standard and have retroactive effect. In reality, this means that all previously compliant implementations that had interpreted vague parts of the standard in their own way become non-compliant if these places turn out to be clarified in some other way by new documents.

   For C90, two such documents were released: [TC-1:1994](https://www.iso.org/standard/24271.html) and [TC-2:1996](https://www.iso.org/standard/27110.html).
2. **ISO Amendment (Amd)**, aka **ISO Normative Addendum (NA)**

   Quite similar in effect to TC and has effectively the same impact, but may limit their retroactive effect through some mechanism - e.g. by introducing a new value of `__STDC_VERSION__`.

   Typically, ISO Amendments are significant and large, so they are issued pretty rarely. But for the C90 one was released anyway - [Amd-1:1995](https://www.iso.org/standard/23909.html).
3. **WG14 Defect Report (DR)**, aka **Clariﬁcation Request**

   These are letters to the Standardization Committee with a request to clarify certain controversial passages in the standard, as well as to draw attention to various kinds of shortcomings in it. Committee addresses them, publicly expressing its collective opinion, which may end up in officially approved document (TC, NA or even the Standard itself).

   However, Defect Reports themselves are not official documents and therefore do not have mandatory retroactive effect. Nevertheless, implementers and ordinary developers can rely on them to avoid the fate of non-conformance in the future or at least reduce the likelihood of its occurrence.

   For the C90 standard, including all the above-mentioned additions, 178 reports were processed, the lists of which are available on the official website of the committee:
   https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr.htm
   https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/c90_drs.html

---

Since the standards do not provide reference (model) implementations neither for the compiler nor for the standard library, this creates a need for their constant clarification and editing. Not all implementers may be interested in supporting new standards in their entirety and not all developers want to rewrite the old code they maintain - this is a fact of life and business. But it is also clear that TC and DR cannot be issued for older standards infinitely.

Thus, the following questions arise:

1. How to treat underspecified behaviour that is not explicitly stated as either *implementation-defined*, *unspecified* or even *undefined*?
2. Should newer standards be referred to in such cases?
3. Should a Defect Report be filed for a withdrawn standard?

Please note that I'm not just talking about compiler and standard library programmers, but also regular code writers.

---

See also:

- [Philosophy behind Undefined Behavior](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99692/philosophy-behind-undefined-behavior)

Comment: I am afraid these blind spots are leftover for compiler implementors.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Avoid code getting you into such situations.

Comment: Regular code writers are much more likely to encounter bugs or performance mistakes in compilers or standard libraries than in language standards.  In my experience probably by a factor of 10.  So specifically from the perspective of people writing application code, I think these questions are somewhat beside the point.  But they certainly are interesting for compiler and library implementors.

Comment: Because, as you wrote, older standard editions are withdrawn, I don't think ISO even offers any avenue for official corrections to them and considers them irrelevant. Defect reports are incorporated into the next standard or a TC (which WG21 did do e.g. for C++03, but doesn't seem to do anymore).

Comment: @user17732522 An official statement like "for anything not covered by this standard, please consult more recent documents" from the standardization committee or ISO itself would be more than enough. This would solve the problem completely.

Comment: @DmitryD.Chernov The C90 standard is officially marked as "Withdrawn" on the very page you linked to.

Comment: @DmitryD.Chernov I doubt that fits ISO's rules and procedures. Being the organization that ISO is, these are also strictly specified. But I am by no means an expert on that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yep, I know. My question is about an issue that seems to be common to all C and C++ standards ever published by the ISO.

Comment: @cher-nov, your latest comment suggests to me that perhaps you have a specific (perceived) language flaw in mind, and are trying to figure out how to proceed with that information.  If so, then I would recommend posing a new question about your perceived flaw in particular.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, by "issue" above I meant the lack of explanations in the standards on approaches to their proper interpretation, especially in cases where they are silent about something. To a certain extent, this is even a philosophical question, in the spirit of the linguistic turn and literary criticism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do the C and C++ standards tell you to deal with situations that are not covered by them?

The language specifications explain how conforming implementations of their respective languages behave.  They say nothing about how *you* should behave.

---

> 1. How to treat underspecified behaviour that is not explicitly stated as either implementation-defined, unspecified or even
>    undefined?

The spec does not have to explicitly say that behavior is undefined.  C in particular defines "undefined behavior" this way:

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

(C17 3.4.3/1).

All versions of the C language specification have this or very similar wording, and I'm pretty sure the same goes for C++.

As for how to treat it, you are safest *avoiding* it. Or for "unspecified" or "implementation defined" behavior, you may be able to ignore it safely if all of the alternatives allowed by the spec are acceptable to you.

Alternatively, if you are specifically targeting an implementation that does define the behavior in question (whether or not the applicable spec makes it "implementation defined"), and you are not concerned about portability to other implementations, then you can rely on your implementation's documentation.

---

> 2. Should newer standards be used in such cases?

It does not make sense to rely on documentation that does not apply to the implementation you are actually using.  It is not safe or reasonable to assume that behavior defined only by a later version of the spec will be manifested by implementations of (only) an earlier version of the spec.

You could, however, consider switching to an implementation of a more recent specification.  See also above.

---

> 3. Should a Defect Report be filed for a withdrawn standard?

That seems unlikely to be useful.  You should understand withdrawl of (a version of) a standard to imply that it will not be further maintained.

In the case of the C and C++ language specifications, if your issue is resolved in a more recent version of the spec then the committee will surely consider that to have adequately addressed it.  If not, then you could consider filing a DR against the current version, with the understanding that any fix will be targeted at that or a future version of the spec.

Comment: _The language specifications explain how conforming implementations of their respective languages behave. They say nothing about how you should behave._ - Definitely, but the implementations themselves are not subjective; they are also written by human programmers. That's what I meant.

Comment: _The spec does not have to explicitly say that behavior is undefined. C in particular defines "undefined behavior" this way: <...>_ - Agreed, but I rather meant behaviour that should not be **undefined** under any circumstances, because otherwise it would make the language partially inconsistent. In other words, these are the issues for which it is worth filing a Defect Report if the affected standard is still active.

Comment: @cher-nov I think a better example for what you mean would be direct self-contradiction in the standard, which for C++ definitively exists and I would be surprised if none existed in C. For example, from the current C++ standard you can deduce that a conforming implementation has to end the following program with exit code `0`: `struct A{};struct B:A{};struct C:A{B b;};C c;int main(){return (A*)&c == (A*)&c.b;};` But you can also deduce that it has to end with exit code `1`.

Comment: @cher-nov: Situations where the C Standard could be interpreted as requiring an implementation to process a program one way, and where it could be interpreted as forbidding such behavior are rare.  Sitautions where it could be interpreted as specifying the behavior of a program, but also specifying that it is equivalent to some other construct over which it waives jurisdiction are common, however, and will only represent a contradiction of waiver of jurisdiction is interpreted as prohibition.

Comment: @cher-nov, "*implementations themselves are not subjective; they are also written by human programmers. That's what I meant.*" -- I do not see the distinction you are trying to draw.  The specs do not tell language implementors what to do, either.  Rather they provide a standard against which implementors' work can be measured -- either "this is a conforming C (or C++) implementation" or not.  And inasmuch as you postulate that implementors might not feel bound to providing a conforming implementation, I see no path from there to the spec telling *anyone* what to do.

Comment: @cher-nov, regarding "*behaviour that should not be undefined under any circumstances, because otherwise it would make the language partially inconsistent*" -- if the spec leaves a given behavior undefined, then that cannot cause any inconsistency in the language as defined.  How could the spec not placing any requirement ever make anything inconsistent?  And inasmuch as you specifically ask about behavior that is not explicitly declared undefined (or implementation defined or unspecified) there cannot even be an inconsistency about whether it is, in fact, undefined.

Comment: @user17732522 how so? There are two `A` subobjects of `C`, which are required to have distinct addresses.

Comment: @Caleth Yes, and at the same time `C` is standard-layout and therefore the `A` base class subobject, as well as the `B` member object have to have offset zero in `C`. `B` is also standard-layout, so its `A` subobject again has to have offset zero. So both `A` subobjects also have to be at the same address, while the general rule forbids this., which is the direct contradiction. This is tracked as [CWG 2736](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2736).

Answer (score 1):

The C89/C90 Standard was written to describe a family of dialects that were already in use, some of which specified behavior in circumstances where others were not.  Rather than try to fully describe everything necessary to make a language suitable for any particular purpose served by these dialects, the Standard limited itself to aspects which were common to all C dialects.

When the Standard was written, there existed a substantial corpus of programs that were written for implementations that would process certain constructs "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment", targeting environments that documented the constructs' behavior in some useful fashion, at the same time as there were implementations written for other platforms which did not specify such behaviors.  Rather than mandate that all implementations must emulate the commonplace behaviors, or that all conforming programs jump through hoops to accommodate the limitations of a few obscure implementations, the Standard simply waived jurisdiction on the presumption that people seeking to sell implementations would make a bona fide effort to make them useful to their customers.

According to the C99 Rationale (though the principle hadn't changed since C89/C90; emhasis original):

> The terms *unspecified behavior*, *undefined behavior*, and *implementation-defined* behavior are used to categorize the result of writing programs whose properties the Standard does not, or cannot, completely describe. The goal of adopting this categorization is to allow a certain variety among implementations which permits *quality of implementation* to be an active force in the marketplace as well as to allow certain popular extensions, without removing the cachet of *conformance to the Standard*. Informative Annex J of the Standard catalogs those behaviors which fall into one of these three categories.

Note that the fact that one compiler happens to process an "Implementation-defined" construct in a manner different from another wouldn't really seem like an "extension", nor would the fact that e.g. an implementation specifies that the order in which function arguments will be evaluated.  The fact that an implementation would process some construct over which the Standard waives jurisdiction, "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment", however, would greatly extend the semantics available to a programmer who was using that implementation and understood the environment in question.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about C and C++ here, for which the respective working groups are WG14 and WG21. But that's looking at the wrong level when it comes to how these working groups operate. WG14 and WG22 are both part of SC22 (programming languages), and the procedures are defined there.

"Undefined behavior", "Unspecified Behavior", "Implementation-defined" and similar terminology on the other hand are specific to C and C++ (and *not even identical* between the two), not SC22.

Hence, your questions are mixing different levels and make little sense as a result.

<sub>SC22 also covered Algol, which is no longer maintained at all. ISO still carries the Algol standard though, because of the historical significance. I learned the details because SC22 was about to retire Algol entirely, and the Dutch SC22 delegation got up in arms over it. But lacking a Working Group, it's obvious that there is no point in filing a DR on Algol.</sub>